# Ano Hana's opening mentions "misanga". What exactly is that?

Tags: japanese-language, music, anohana

In Ano Hana's opening theme "Aoi Shiori", the word **misanga** was mentioned a few times.

> Ichipeeji mekuru tenohira   kuchibiru de musunda **misanga**
>
> Nee kyou mo kawaranai kyou de   ame fureba denwa mo dekiru yo
>
> Sou yatte ima wa kimi no hou e (itsu no ma ni ka kireta **misanga**)
>
> Oshitsukeru boku no yasashisa wo (demo nazeka ienai mama da yo)
>
> Hontou douka shiteru mitai

which means..

> My hand that turns to the next page, and the **misanga** I fastened with my lips...
>
> Hey, today is today, and that won't change; if it rains, we can still talk on the phone.
>
> In that way, I now push (Before I knew it, the **misanga** came off,)
>
> My kindness in your direction. (But for some reason, I can't say it.)
>
> There really must be something wrong with me.

The translation didn't give the exact meaning of the word "misanga" so I was wondering what it is.

Comment: I have a suspicion that this question could better fit [japanese.se] since it's just about a certain japanese word.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A misanga is a type of handicraft good luck charm, similar in concept to friendship bracelets, they are typically made from knotted embroidery floss, thread, gimp, or similar material. Like friendship bracelets, they are tied together by simple knots.

It is said that if you make a wish when you tie the ends together, your wish will come true when the bracelet falls off from wear.

The etymology of the name seems to come from the Portuguese word for "beads" (miçanga). They were [first popularized](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9F%E3%82%B5%E3%83%B3%E3%82%AC) in 1993 during the beginning of the [J-League](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E3%83%97%E3%83%AD%E3%82%B5%E3%83%83%E3%82%AB%E3%83%BC%E3%83%AA%E3%83%BC%E3%82%B0), the Japan Professional Football League. Ramos Ruy and Tsuyoshi Kitazawa of the Tokyo Verde football club wore these to wish for the victory of their team.

The idea behind it may have changed but it's intended to be a symbol of good luck and friendship.

[image: Make a wish]

Comment: It is also said that when a misanga naturally comes apart and falls off the wrist, it is an omen that a wish will come true.